# How do create a sound to express a soft, baritone-like pleasurable emotion?

Tags: sound-design

I studied sound quality in mechanical engineering.  I want to create a luxurious car horn sound that can connect with emotions.

Can you recommend how I might create a sound to express a soft, baritone-like pleasurable emotion?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are after and not entirely sure what you mean by 'luxurious' car horn... Are you wanting to describe the timbre of a certain car horn sound using words? And do you have any examples of a particular type of horn you are able to post a link to?

Timbre, or 'how something sounds', is usually described using words you'd normally relate with other senses, such as vision and touch. For example, a sound can be described as warm or cold, sharp or soft, bright or dull.

Words I'd use to describe a typical car horn would be things like 'sharp', 'bright', maybe 'harsh'. The point of a car horn is to act as a warning so will tend to be be disharmonic and cutting so as to stand out and catch our attention.

Again, if you post a link to a more specific example of what you're attempting to describe, we might be able to give you more assistance!!

Comment: Good effort. ;) 

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest listening to animal sounds first and then analyze those which have tone and expression similar to what you are looking for. Besides timbre (overall spectrum) there're also other important properties such as intonation (pitch changes) and articulation which define emotional response.